# "Завод-изготовитель котла" — здесь дефис или тире?

Tags: орфография, дефис-тире

Завод-изготовитель котла или завод - изготовитель котла? Дефис или тире с пробелами?

Comment: Нужно знать предложение целиком. Оба варианта возможны.

Comment: Это сложное слово. Обе части равноправны. Как пловец-перворязрядник и т.п. Выбираем дефис.

Comment: Не вижу ничего особо крамольного в этих словах. В большинстве случаев именно так и есть.  
Посему восстанавливаю справедливость.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут действительно возможны варианты.
Но в документах и технической литературе случаи, требующие тире, вряд ди встретятся.
Почти наверняка - дефис: "завод-изготовитель", это уже на уровне термина:

"ЗАМЕНУ ПРОВОДА ПИТАЮЩЕГО ПРОИЗВОДИТ ЗАВОД-ИЗГОТОВИТЕЛЬ ЭЛЕКТРОНАСОСА",

"Основанием к отмене определения послужило то, что при втором обращении Л. в суд ответчиком по делу указан завод-изготовитель мебели, в то время как при первоначальном его обращении им являлся продавец мебели, т.е. иски предъявлялись к разным лицам, а следовательно, не могла быть применена вышеуказанная норма закона как основание для отказа в принятии заявления".

"В обоих вариантах завод-изготовитель тракторной техники будет иметь возможность выпускать машины в двух исполнениях: оснащенные дополнительным комплектом для дистанционного управления; в стандартном исполнении, т.е. без такого комплекта. [М. Н. Котровский. Дистанционно-автоматизированное управление машинами // «Горная промышленность», 2004"

и т.д.
(Нацкорпус)

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, возможны оба варианта. Правильнее было вопрос сформулировать так : ДЕФИС В СЛОВЕ или ТИРЕ В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ?